# Which of the following polynomials are separable?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Which of the following polynomials are separable?

a)$\;t^4-8t^2+16\in\mathbb{Q}[t]$

b)$\;t^{17}-t\in\ \mathbb{F}_{17}[t]$

c)$\;t^{17}-X^{17}\in \mathbb{F}_{17}(X)[t]$

a) My first idea to use the following: A polynomial $p(x)$ is separable iff $(p(x),p^{\prime}(x))=1$

If I use the above then if we let $ p(t)=t^4-8t^2+16$ then $p^{\prime}(t)=4t^3-16t$ and then $(p(t),p^{\prime}(t))=1$ thus the polynomial should be separable over $\mathbb{Q}$

On the other hand we have definition that a polynomial is separable if all its roots are simple (i.e of multiplicity one)

The roots are of multiplicity 2

$4t^4-8t^2+16=(t-2)^2(t+2)^2$

Which would imply it is not separable.....

Then we had a theorem which say that in $char=0$ all **irreducible** polynomials are separable...but $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{Q})=0$ and the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$...

I am really confused here.

**Any ideas?**

b)$\;t^{17}-t=0\\t(t^{16}-1)=0\\t\Bigl(\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{15}(t-\epsilon^{i})\Bigr)=0$ 
$\epsilon=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{16}}=e^{\frac{\pi i}{8}}$

All linear factors are of multiplicity 1 so the polynomial should be separable.

Moreover $(t^{17}-t,-1)=1$ thus the polynomial is separable.

c)
$(t^{17}-X^{17},0)\neq 1$

Hence the polynomial is not separable

Comment: The idea of calculating $(p,p')$ is a good one (+1 even). Something just went wrong with your calculation in part a). Note that both $p$ and $p'$ are divisible by $t^2-4$.

Comment: Your conclusion in part b) is correct, but observe that the field $\Bbb{Z}_{17}$ does not contain any complex numbers. It does contain other sixteenth roots of unity, but I would just go with the gcd here. Same in part c).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: You are right with a) I made a mistake there when calculating gcd. So the polynomial is **not** separable?

Comment: I have a question to a). If I had a polynomial that were irreducible could I then just write then in $char=0$ every irreducible polynomial is separable?

Comment: Correct (to both). In characteristic zero irreducible polynomials are separable, because their derivative is non-zero, of a lower degree, and thus cannot have common factors with the original one.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction (just a mixstake in the computations!) in what you say for the rational numbers since the polynomial you give is not irreducible as you saw. So it can be non-separable.

And there are two ways of proving it: either you can find all roots in an algebraic closure of $K$ and it is separable if and only if it has only roots with multiplicity one. Or, you compute the gdc of $P$ and $P'$ (a.k.a the discriminant of $P$) and $P$ is separable iff the gcd is $1$ (try to prove the equivalence of the assertions).

It is easy to compute the gcd between two polynomials whereas it is in general not possible to find its roots. So, you should always compute the gcd. For a), $P(t) = t^4 - 8t^2 + 16$ and $P'(t) = 4t(t^2 -4)$. You find $gcd(P(t),P'(t)) = t^2 - 4$ so the polynomial is not separable. For b), $P'(t) = -1$, so $P$ is seaparable. For c), $P(t) = t^{17} - X^{17}$ ad $P'(t) = 0$. So $P$ is not seaparable.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. Sometimes I do problems mechanically without thinking :). Good advice above. I will remember that.